# Add multiple items to CheckedListBox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, checkedlistbox

I want to add all lines from TextBox1 into CheckedListBox1 as items.

I tried `CheckedListBox1.Items.AddRange(TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine))`
 but it doesn't work (it adds only empty items).

Answer (score 0):

Try this **UPDATE**

```
CheckedListBox1.DataSource = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine).toList()
```

Comment: ohh yea my bad. You're supposed to loop that to add it to the list. Try my updated code.

Comment: I've put exact code as above and it's still same. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with codes, this one worked.

```
Dim parts As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)

CheckedListBox1.Items.AddRange(parts)
```